# XPATH for matching nodes with wildcard and having one attribute but not one other

Tags: xml, xpath

again one xpath is making my life hard. Whaat i need to do is to find all "Module_X" Nodes that do have a @ModuleGUID but no @PresetGUID.
In this example it should Match both Module_1 .

```
<xml>
<Parent1>
        <Module_0 ModuleGUID="1" PresetGUID="1">
            <ModuleData />
        </Module_0>
        <Module_1 ModuleGUID="{123}" >
                <ModuleData Complexity="0" />
        </Module_1>
</Parent1>
<Parent2>
            <Module_0 ModuleGUID="4" PresetGUID="5">
                <ModuleData />
            </Module_0>
            <Module_1 ModuleGUID="{456}" >
                    <ModuleData Complexity="0" />
            </Module_1>
</Parent2>
</xml>
```

What i tried is to reduce it and try to only match only modules_0 that have ModuleGUID but not PresetGUID but still i just cannot find out how to combine the "must have AND must not have" stuff

i tried tons of combinations like that but none worked for me:

```
//Module_0[@ModuleGuid and not(@PresetGuid)]
```

EDIT: this simplified example does not work, i dont know the correct syntax for "match this where that is missing" syntax. The final XPATH would look like this

```
//*[contains(.,'Module_')] [@ModuleGuid and not(@PresetGuid)]
```

Comment: *it should only match the first Module_0* - but the first Module_0 has PresetGUID="1". Elaborate your condition

Comment: Basically i want to match any node in the whole xml where ModuleGUID is present but PresetGUID is not but any clue to get to the goal is welcome ;-)9

Comment: your condition covers `Module_1 ModuleGUID="{123}"` and `Module_1 ModuleGUID="{456}"` - is that what you need?

Comment: What i need is more like this but even my example above dont work, i dont know how to combine the "match this but not that attribute" //*[contains(.,'Module_')] [@ModuleGuid and not(@PresetGuid)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath is case sensitive. Instead of PresetGuid, it's PresetGUID and so on... Also, I'm assuming `contains()` needs to be applied to the name of the tag, not the text between open and close tags. Try:

```
//*[contains(local-name(),'Module_') and not(@PresetGUID) and @ModuleGUID]
```

Returns

```
<Module_1 ModuleGUID="{123}">
    <ModuleData Complexity="0"/>
</Module_1>
<Module_1 ModuleGUID="{456}">
    <ModuleData Complexity="0"/>
</Module_1>
```

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//*[starts-with(name(),'Module_')][@ModuleGUID][not(@PresetGUID)]]
```

will select all elements whose name starts with `Module_` that have a `@ModuleGUID` attribute but do have a `@PresetGUID` attribute, as requested.